# An example of a discontinuous function on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

I wanted to construct

> a discontinuous function $f$ so that it's domain and range is compact .

Here is my example which I gave thought of :

$f:[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

$f(x)=1$ (when $x$ is rational)

$ f(x)=0$ (when $x$ is irrational)

Is this example ok? Can someone suggest some more examples.

Comment: Can you suggest an example in R with any other topology?

Comment: Or what about trying to make $f$ bijective?

Comment: Yes, do you have an example when f is bijective. I can't find one

Comment: @Bungo is the zero function discontinuous?

Comment: @HankIgoe Oops, sorry, I don't know how I overlooked that!

Comment: Yes it's ok, this is Dirichlet function restricted to $[a,b]$.

Comment: My line of thought would be $f(x)=x^2$ on $[-1,1]$, then set $f(0.5)=1$ to make is discontiuous. Range of that $f$ is still $[0,1]$.